# Performing basic math on an object project but value returns NaN

Tags: javascript, object

I'm currently learning about JS objects and trying to perform basic subtraction on a property that is then outputted via a method. However, the object method returns value of NaN even though `typeof` tells me `currentAge` and `currentYear`are numbers. What am I doing wrong and How can I get my below method to output the correct number?

```js
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();

var Sam = {
  age: 27, //Number
  birthMonth: "March", //March
  currentYear: year, //number
  birthYear: this.currentYear - this.age,

  // Method to say birth year
  sayBirthYear: function(){
    console.log("I was born in the year " + this.birthYear );     
    //return NANS
  }
}

Sam.sayBirthYear(); // Outputs Birth year
```

Comment: When `this.currentYear - this.age` executes `this` is not the object referenced by `Sam` in fact that object hasn't even been created yet, and `currentYear` and `age` are not available as properties of any object at that point.

Comment: ...and the solution might be `sayBirthYear: function () { console.log("I was born in the year " + (this.currentYear - this.age));} `

Comment: @Paulpro actually, in that moment is using the `window` object.

Comment: @Paulpro You are correct. I think I understand.

Comment: @dhilt Yup. When it is put inside the method it works

Answer (score 0):

The context `this` is not making reference to the current object `Sam`, but the enclosing context, in this case the `window` context.

An alternative is using a function, and create objects from it.  That way, the enclosing context would be the function:

```js
var Sam = function () {
  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();

  this.age = 27;
  this.birthMonth = "March";
  this.currentYear = year;
  this.birthYear = this.currentYear - this.age;
  
  // Method to say birth year
  this.sayBirthYear = function() {
    console.log("I was born in the year " + this.birthYear );     
  }
}

new Sam().sayBirthYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

When `this.currentYear - this.age` executes `this` is not the object referenced by `Sam`. In fact that object hasn't even been created yet, and `currentYear` and `age` are not available as properties of any object at that point. You have a few options for achieving the behaviour you want.

You can add the birthYear property after the object is created like this:

```js
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();

var Sam = {
  age: 27,
  birthMonth: "March",
  currentYear: year,

  // Method to say birth year
  sayBirthYear: function(){
    console.log("I was born in the year " + this.birthYear ); 
  }
}

Sam.birthYear = Sam.currentYear - Sam.age;

Sam.sayBirthYear(); // Outputs Birth year
```

or you can do it during object creation like this:

```js
var today = new Date( );
var year = today.getFullYear( );

var Sam = new function ( ) {
  this.age = 27;
  this.birthMonth = "March";
  this.currentYear = year;
  this.birthYear = this.currentYear - this.age;

  // Method to say birth year
  this.sayBirthYear = function ( ) {
    console.log( "I was born in the year " + this.birthYear );
  };
};

Sam.sayBirthYear( ); // Outputs Birth year
```

or you can make birthYear a getter like this:

```js
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();

var Sam = {
  age: 27,
  birthMonth: "March",
  currentYear: year,
  get birthYear() { return this.currentYear - this.age; },

  // Method to say birth year
  sayBirthYear: function(){
    console.log("I was born in the year " + this.birthYear ); 
  }
}

Sam.sayBirthYear(); // Outputs Birth year
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `this` is `window` by default :

```
john = { whoami: this }
john.whoami // window
```

You must put it into a function to be able to change its value :

```
function whoami () { return this; }
john = { whoami: whoami }
jack = { whoami: whoami }
whoami() // window
john.whoami() // john
jack.whoami() // jack
whoami.call(john) // john
whoami.call(jack) // jack
```